# match function arg in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a function in R take can take some default values or a custom-user function:

```
myfun = function(x = c('funA', 'funB', 'funC'), customFUN = NULL)
{
}
```

If the user chooses any default-listed value for x, customFUN will be ignored.
What's the best way to handle this in R?

I COULD use

```
myfun = function(x = c('funA', 'funB', 'funC'), customFUN = NULL)
{

  if (! is.null(customFUN)) {
    choosenFUN = match.fun(customFUN)
  }
  else {
    choosenFUN.string = match.arg(x)

    if (choosenFUN == 'funA')
       choosenFUN = algorithmA
    else if (choosenFUN == 'funB')
       choosenFUN = algorithmB
    #...and so on for the other defaults
  }

}
```

but it seems weird to add the extra arg customFUN, maybe there's a clever way to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: I would use either `switch` or an `if` statement.

Comment: You could use a single argument and test for `is.function`.

Comment: If you are happy for your users to pass a function rather than the name of a function, you could first have `if (is.function(x))`...

Comment: The user should be able to pass a function name, a anonymous function or some default arg in the list.

Comment: nominate an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it, thanks to the comments:

```
myfun = function(x = c('funA', 'funB', 'funC'))
{
  if (is.function(x))
    func = x
  else                  
    func.string = switch(match.arg(x), funA = 'UseA', funB = 'UseB', funC = 'Usec')

  if (func.string == 'UseA') 
    func = algorithmA
  else if (func.string == 'UseB')
    func = algorithmB
  # and so on

  func
}
```

Comment: While you're there, you might do `func <- switch(match.arg(x), funA = algorithmA, funB = algorithmA, funC = algorithmA )`